# Meaning of "deliver the report"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I want to say that someone had prepared the report and ,afterwards, spoke at the discussion based on their report.

> X spoke and delivered their report at the discussion.

Is it correct usage of this phrase?

Comment: *Gave their report* or *made their report* or *presented their report* are all common possibilities.

Comment: I would be more inclined to say he **spoke from** the report.  I know it sounds odd, but there is an idiom "to speak from notes", and this sounds like an instance of that sense.  He is not just reading the report, right?  He is giving a presentation _based on_ the report, which he had in hand.

Comment: I think it may be simpler to just say that that someone reported the thing they had prepared in the report at that discussion. For example, if it's about a scientific research, you could say that that someone *reported their findings* at the discussion.

Comment: I'm bewildered by the word _delivered_ in the sentence .Also, _"X spoke"_ and _"delivered their report"_ since it's suggesting me there are more than 1 people in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> X delivered their report

[Deliver](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deliver) in this context would mean that X read out the report before an audience: compare with the first example in the reference:

> The priest delivered a passionate sermon/speech against war.

If there was subsequently a discussion about the content of the report, you could say

> X delivered their report and participated in the discussion that followed.

If X distributed a copy of the report in writing and then attended a meeting to discuss the content of the report, you could say

> X circulated the report and then participated in a discussion about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.  "spoke and delivered the report" is either conjoined in meaning or disjunct in meaning.

- (spoke and delivered) the report

  This cannot be right, as one does not "speak" a report. One can "report" something, or "read a report".
- (spoke) and (delivered the report)

Here it is not certain what he spoke about. He might have spoken on some other topic altogether, and just happened to deliver the report at that same meeting.

So how to make it clear that he both delivered the report and spoke about it?

- He delivered the report and spoke about it at the discussion.

Or, if his talk was an essential part of "delivery", and he spoke with that report in hand, you might say

- He spoke from the report {,which/that} he brought to the discussion.

Comment: He spoke on other topics and gave the report at the same time.

Comment: In that case, I would say he "spoke, and also delivered his report". That leads the reader to at least consider that he might have spoken on another topic.  Of course, if you can say which topic he did speak on, that would remove all ambiguity. "He spoke on X, and delivered his report on Y."